# Module : net.iamyellow.gcmjs : how can i open window automatically when receiving notification push

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

I'm using `net.iamyellow.gcmjs` module for notification push (android), I want to open a window automatically when I receive push notification (even my app in background), without user interaction.

Comment: Please try few things out from your side and then ask for help on resolving the issue, rather than completely relying on getting answer from stack overflow

Comment: This is exactly what I do. thank you :)

Comment: @HamidMly, what you are asking for is simply impossible on this earth. It cannot be done in anyway. :)

Comment: ok @PrashantSaini, thank you ^^, what i want is like Alarm app, (open window when receiving notif). thank you again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GCM's only role in this process is to send a payload coming from your app server to the GCM connection server then into your client app *(device)*. What you do with the payload on the client side is totally up to you.

But what is commonly used in order to show the user when a push notification is received is by showing a [Notification](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html). You can try out the [GCM Android Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/start) in order to get the gist.

In the code that you will be downloading *(if ever you decided to try the quicstart)*, the `MyGCMListenerService` *(responsible for listening when a push notification is sent to the device)* it has the `sendNotifcation()` function which generates a `Notification` for the user to see.

Here's about [Building a Notification](http://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/build-notification.html). Do try it out. GCM is fun and vast. Cheers! :D

Comment: Thanks for the explanation :D